# Inconsistent results between NIntegrate and Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics

I get these inconsistent results
[image]

What is going wrong? Fast oscillating terms? Small exponential factors?
But then, why the result seems to toggle between values 1 and 2, rather than being a real number?

EDIT:

```
Module[{\[Beta] = 1.0, \[Epsilon] = 0.99},
  NIntegrate[2/(\[Pi] (1 + E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) (E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \[Epsilon]^2)) Cos[4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]), {\[Alpha]r, -50, 50}, {\[Alpha]i, -50, 50}]]

Module[{\[Beta] = 4.0, \[Epsilon] = 0.99},
  NIntegrate[2/(\[Pi] (1 + E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) (E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \[Epsilon]^2)) Cos[4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]), {\[Alpha]r, -50, 50}, {\[Alpha]i, -50, 50}]]
```

Comment: Please upload your equations as copy-paste-able Mathematica code so that potential respondents can copy it to their notebooks and experiment with it. Thanks.

Comment: c'mon @m135, you have been around before, you should know by now that we considered it helpful and polite to show your own efforts and share your data and code attempts in a well [formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX), so we can copy, paste and quickly see the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the result of

```
\[Alpha]=4;\[Epsilon]=99/100;Plot3D[2/(\[Pi] (1 +  E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) (E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - 
\[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 
E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 
2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \[Epsilon]^2)) 
Cos[4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]), {\[Alpha]r, -10, 10}, {\[Alpha]i, -2, 2}, 
PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, WorkingPrecision->20]
```

[image]

you will see a weird plot. Outside of this rectangle the integrand takes
very small values, e.g. `N[2/(\[Pi] (1 +  E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) (E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - \[Beta] \ \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) +  E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) +  2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \ \[Epsilon]^2)) Cos[4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]) /. {\[Alpha]r ->  10, \[Alpha]i -> 10}]` results in `1.80913*10^-119`. Because of the big
ranges of the integration `{\[Alpha]r, -50, 50}` and `{\[Alpha]i, -50, 50}`
`NIntegrate` produces an incorrect result

```
\[Beta] = 4; \[Epsilon] = 99/100; NIntegrate[2/(\[Pi] (1 + 
   E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) (E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) 
+ E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 
2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) 
E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \[Epsilon]^2)) Cos[4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]),
 {\[Alpha]r, -50,  50}, {\[Alpha]i, -50, 50}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

> `1.00000000055400`

without any warning and error communication. This definitely is a bug.

A narrowing of the ranges of the integration is a workaround. Indeed,

```
Integrate[ 2/(\[Pi] (1 +  E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) 
(E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 
 E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 
 2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) 
E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \[Epsilon]^2)) Cos[4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]), {\[Alpha]r, -50,  50}, 
{\[Alpha]i, -50, 50}] // N
```

> `2. + 0. I`

The same result is obtained when integrating over `{\[Alpha]r, -10, 10}, {\[Alpha]i, -3, 3}`.
This is in accordance with

```
NIntegrate[ 2/(\[Pi] (1 + E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) 
(E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 
E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) + 
2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) 
E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \[Epsilon]^2)) Cos[4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]),
 {\[Alpha]r, -10,  10}, {\[Alpha]i, -3, 3}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

> `1.99999980395600`

Comment: We also may widen the ranges: `NIntegrate[  2/(\[Pi] (1 +         E^(-2 (\[Beta]^2)))) (E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r - \[Beta] \ \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) +      E^(-2 ((\[Alpha]r + \[Beta] \[Epsilon])^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) +      2 E^(-2 (\[Alpha]r^2 + \[Alpha]i^2)) E^(-2 \[Beta]^2 (1 - \ \[Epsilon]^2)) Cos[       4 \[Alpha]i \[Beta] \[Epsilon]]), {\[Alpha]r, -Infinity,    Infinity}, {\[Alpha]i, -Infinity, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 15]` results in `1.99998076288872`.